# Remove table prefix from column name - Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Is there a way to remove table prefix automotically from existing tables?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by after? Do you mean without returning to power query?

Comment: I have alright create the tables and now i want to remove the prefix from the columns.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you currently have, what you've tried and what you're expecting to your question?

Comment: Explain what you mean by AFTER they were created? Will a PowerQuery solution work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Double click the name of the column in the data pane and remove the prefix or type anything you like.

[image]

Comment: This is manual process. Is there any automated one?

Comment: You can batch rename in tabular editor. Details: https://pawarbi.github.io/blog/powerbi/tabulareditor/2022/08/30/adding-prefix-to-selected-columns-powerbi.html

Comment: Curenlty i do not manage to find any solution and i remove the prefix manually.